# Jquery function cannot access global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jquery click functions that sets and retrieves value from a javascript object.

```
var poly;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    //save drawing
    $("#save").click( function () {
        poly = new Polygon();
        poly.savedrawingaspoly(map.polygonevent);
        poly.tract = tract;
        poly.name = $('#polyname').val();
        console.log(poly);
    });

    $("#btnClear").click(function () {
        console.log(poly);
        //poly.clearplot();
    });
});
```

the `console.log(poly);` in `$("#save").click` works.  the `console.log(poly);` in `$("#btnClear").click` returns undefined. How do I spread the scope of the variable, so the second one can see the variable?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you clicking btnClear before save ?

Comment: Gonna second this, is btnClear being clicked before save? Otherwise, this code should work...

Comment: Write this line in above top: 

var poly;
poly = new Polygon();

Comment: At the first line, you only declare a variable called `poly` without defining it (you do not assign a value to `poly`).
So if you click `btnClear` before `Save`, you'll get `undefined`.
Inside the `Save` click callback, you assign `new Polygon()` to `poly` so it works fine.

Comment: but if we assign then their problem solved

Comment: well, crap. Thanks much guys.

Comment: You declared the variable correctly; but not handled the event. If someone click btnClear first; the variable will always be undefined, no matter if you have declared it globally.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **window** object to keep your variable in browser context. So the new code will look like:

```
$("#save").click( function () {
        poly = new Polygon();
        poly.savedrawingaspoly(map.polygonevent);
        poly.tract = tract;
        poly.name = $('#polyname').val();
        console.log(poly);

        window.poly = poly;
});
```

After implementing the code mentioned above; you can access **poly** variable through any function and also through your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You can store and access the object at `.data()` of `#save` jQuery object

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //save drawing
    $("#save").click( function () {
        $(this).data().poly = new Polygon();
        $(this).data().poly.savedrawingaspoly(map.polygonevent);
        $(this).data().poly.tract = tract;
        $(this).data().poly.name = $('#polyname').val();
        console.log($(this).data().poly);
    });

    $("#btnClear").click(function () {
        if ($("#save").data().poly !== undefined) {
          $("#save").data().poly.clearplot();
        } else {
          console.log($("#save").data())
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Barmar Your initial comment did compel a re-read of Answer and alert to the fact that was missing `$("#save").data()` part of approach at `$("#btnClear")` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Define like global and use it across the events and function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //save drawing
    var poly = new Polygon();
    $("#save").click( function () {
        poly.savedrawingaspoly(map.polygonevent);
        poly.tract = tract;
        poly.name = $('#polyname').val();
        console.log(poly);
    });

    $("#btnClear").click(function () {
        console.log(poly);
        //poly.clearplot();
    });
});
```